# How to turn automerge on by default?

Tags: interface

[image]

Auto merge is not on by default. How do I make it enabled by default?

Comment: to add to Hiserod's answer, Auto-Merge should not be enabled by default, so you must have saved a startup file with it enabled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Save Startup File

To change the default settings in Blender, you can open a fresh file, tweak it to your liking, and save the file as your startup file.

To change the startup file navigate to *Header → File → Defaults → Save Startup File.*

[image: 1]